# Need JSON api link for worldcoinindex site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, bitcoin

I want to get coins values from www.worldcoinindex.com. Can anyone know how to get the json data from worldcoinindex via api.

Comment: What have you done so far? any research? code?

Comment: I have done little research about api, but i didt get any info about api. I got some github project links about worldcoinindex. Here is Github link : https://github.com/worldcoinproject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=384546.msg4976342#msg4976342) linked from the site, there is no API. You'll have to scrape for now.

**Edit**:

There is now an API; docs at https://www.worldcoinindex.com/apiservice